# Domain masking with serverless automation

Tags: url-rewriting, web-deployment, serverless-framework

We are running microsites for our clients each Microsite is a sub domain of the main site.

All sub domains are controlled by vapor.Laravel

We are trying to find a way we can mask the URL so instead of being clientname.our name.io it could show whatever the client wants it to show. We know we need to manage getting to the site as that URL would not navigate them there.

My question is it seems domain masking isn’t working on the serverless design we have. Has anyone successfully made it work? If so any advise?

Comment: You want `customdomain.io` to point to `clientname.ourname.io`? If so look into CNAME DNS records.

Comment: no we want client name.ourname.io to just appear as customdomain.io on all pages

Comment: Isn't that what I said though? You want that when people type in `customdomain.io` they should be shown what they would see if they type `clientname.ourname.io`, no?

Comment: no they will be brought by link they will not type anything in. So the link will go to client name.ourname.io but once they get there we only want them to see custom domain.io custom domain.io actually will not point to this site.

Comment: Okay, I think I got this now. You want them to be sent by link to `clientname.ourname.io`, but once there, you want them to see `customdomain.io` instead of `clientname.ourname.io` as the url?

Comment: correct and its all a severless/managed domain with vapor and running into issues doing this. I know you can do it on a typical HTML page...

Comment: Then as I said, buy the domain `customdomain.io` and give a CNAME record pointing to `clientname.ourname.io`, and send them with the link to `customdomain.io` instead. It is the only ***right*** way to it. Doing it any other certainly wont allow you to get a SLL certificate for the website.